# Rails Nested Forms Not Saving or Validating On Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have the following controller:

```
class Admin::ArticleChangeRequestsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: :index
  before_action :set_article_change_request, only: [:edit, :delete]
  helper SortClassHelper

  protected
  def set_order
    if params[:column].present?
      @column = params[:column]
    else
      @column = 'created_at'
    end

    if params[:sort].present?
      @sort = params[:sort]
    else
      @sort = 'desc'
    end

    @order = @column.to_s + ' ' + @sort.to_s
  end

  def set_article_change_request
    @article_change_request = ArticleChangeRequest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def article_change_request_params
    params[:article_change_request].permit(:title, :change, :article)
  end

  public
  def index
    @article_change_requests = ArticleChangeRequest.order(@order).page params[:page]
  end

  def edit
    if request.patch?
      if @article_change_request.update(article_change_request_params)
        redirect_to :admin_article_change_requests, :flash => { success: t(:article_change_request_updated) }
      end
    end
  end

  def delete
    if request.post?
      if @article_change_request.delete
        flash[:success] = t(:article_change_request_deleted)

        render :json => { :success => true }
      else
        render :json => { :success => false }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and have added:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :article
```

in my ArticleChangeRequest model. However whenever I hit Update it does not validate or save the article. Here is my Form:

```
<%= form_for @article_change_request, { :url => :admin_article_change_request_edit } do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { f: f }  %>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit t(:update), class: 'submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if @article_change_request.errors.any? %>
  <div class="message errormsg">
    <p>
      <%= t :there_is %> <%= pluralize @article_change_request.errors.count, t(:error) %>
    </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="container">
  <%= f.label :title, t(:change_request_title) + ':' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, size: 40, class: 'text' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.errors[:title].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.errors[:title].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.errors[:title].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <%= f.label :change, t(:change_request_change) + ':' %>
  <%= f.text_area :change, size: '100x5' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.errors[:change].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.errors[:change].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.errors[:change].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<hr>
<%= f.fields_for :article do |a| %>
<div class="container">
  <%= a.label :category_id, t(:article_category) + ':' %>
  <%= a.select :category_id, [''].concat(Category.select_options) %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:category_id].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:category_id].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:category_id].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <%= a.label :title, t(:article_title) + ':' %>
  <%= a.text_field :title, size: 40, class: 'text' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:title].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:title].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:title].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <%= a.label :slug, t(:article_slug) + ':' %>
  <%= a.text_field :slug, size: 40, class: 'text slug' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:slug].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:slug].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:slug].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <%= a.label :article_type, t(:article_type) + ':' %>
  <%= a.select :article_type, [''].concat(ArticleType.select_options) %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:article_type].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:article_type].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:article_type].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div id="article_content_container" class="container" style="display: none;">
  <%= a.label :content, t(:article_content) + ':' %>
  <%= a.text_area :content, size: '100x40', class: 'wysiwyg' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:content].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:content].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:content].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div id="article_link_container" class="container" style="display: none;">
  <%= a.label :link, t(:article_link) + ':' %>
  <%= a.text_field :link, size: 40, class: 'text' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:link].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:link].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:link].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <%= a.label :summary, t(:article_summary) + ':' %>
  <%= a.text_area :summary, size: '100x5' %>
  <% unless @article_change_request.article.errors[:summary].blank? then %>
  <span class="note error">
    <% @article_change_request.article.errors[:summary].each do |e| %>
      <% if e == @article_change_request.article.errors[:summary].last %>
        <%= e %>
      <% else %>
        <%= e %>,
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone tell me why its not validating or updating?

Comment: You need to permit article params.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992166/rails-4-nested-form-fields-not-saving-in-database?rq=1
Similiar question

Comment: But am I not here: params[:article_change_request].permit(:title, :change, :article) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params[:article_change_request].permit(:title, :change,
:article_attributes => {:category_id, :title, :slug, :article_type})
```

Comment: Cool, how do I make it so the associated model is updated instead of having it try to be created?

Comment: <%= form_for @article_change_request, { :url => :admin_article_change_request_edit }, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>

Comment: Its updating the Change Request but creating a new associated Article on every save.